# Matching variations (misspell, leetspeak) of words

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I'm in need for a library that would match words, given a threshold, that are misspelled or leetspeak variations of another, for instance `Antoine` would match:

```
4ntoine
4toine
antoine
4t01n3
titoine
entoine
a n t o i n e
```

Etc. How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: A basic start would be with a simple DP algorithm for spell checking. Then it could perhaps be augmented with heuristics to limit the results (and increase the space). Of course, I suspect this has been tackled in various "bad word filter" libraries.

Comment: [Levenstein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_Distance)

Comment: Thanks @jlordo, I was missing the vocabulary to express what my problem is.  That's a good lead.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Comment: I've found an implementation in the Apache Commons : `StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/). This was originally developed by IBM then did not seem much maintained.

I do not know what the status is today but we successfully used it to do something close to what you are trying to achieve. Not sure you can handle l33t with it though.

Also check [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jazzy/)

Answer (score 0):

The Levenstein distance may help but some heuristic rules may be applied first AMHO.

Please experience the following program:

```
public class LevenshteinDistance
{
   public static int computeDistance( String s1, String s2 )
   {
      s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
      s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
      int[] costs = new int[s2.length() + 1];
      for( int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++ )
      {
         int lastValue = i;
         for( int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++ )
         {
            if( i == 0 ) {
               costs[ j ] = j;
            }
            else
            {
               if( j > 0 )
               {
                  int newValue = costs[ j - 1 ];
                  if( s1.charAt( i - 1 ) != s2.charAt( j - 1 ) ) {
                     newValue =
                        Math.min(
                           Math.min( newValue, lastValue ),
                           costs[ j ] ) + 1;
                  }
                  costs[ j - 1 ] = lastValue;
                  lastValue = newValue;
               }
            }
         }
         if( i > 0 ) {
            costs[ s2.length() ] = lastValue;
         }
      }
      return costs[ s2.length() ];
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String ref = "Antoine";
      String[] samples = {
         "4ntoine", "4ntoine", "antoine", "4nt01n3", "titoine", "entoine",
         "a n t o i n e" };
      for( String sample : samples ) {
         System.out.printf( "| %s | %-20s | %4d |\n",
            ref, sample, computeDistance( ref, sample ));
      }
   }
}
```

The result:

```
| Antoine | 4ntoine              |    1 |
| Antoine | 4ntoine              |    1 |
| Antoine | antoine              |    0 |
| Antoine | 4nt01n3              |    4 |
| Antoine | titoine              |    2 |
| Antoine | entoine              |    1 |
| Antoine | a n t o i n e        |    6 |
```

As you can see the last word should be preprocessed to remove blank spaces and the fourth word should be preprocessed to replace 3 with E and 4 with A.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Levenstein as suggested or trigram as well; http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram_search